# ReplacePart to substitute a row in a Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

I have a very large n x n matrix from which I want to take a row i from and substitute every element with 0. When I try the below command however, the ith row is not replaced by a list of n zeros but a single zero, which breaks the matrix.

```
ReplacePart[A, {i -> {0}}]
```

Is there a neat way of substituting that {0} with some command that produces an automatic list of (length[A]) number of 0s?

Comment: For _in place_ modification (no copy), maybe `A[[4,All]]*=0`

Comment: Another possibility is to use `Dot`, e.g. `DiagonalMatrix[1 - UnitVector[Length[A], i]].A`

Answer (score 10):

```
A = Array[a, {10, 10}];

i = 4;
b = ReplacePart[A, {i, _} -> 0];

b // MatrixForm
```

[image]

You can also do

```
c = A; c[[i, ;;]] = 0;

d = MapAt[0 & /@ # &, A, {i}];

e = MapAt[0 &, A, {i, All}];

b == c == d == e
```

> ```
> True
> ```